# HWMon interface for I2C thermal device (TMP102, 3.10) - missing sysfs files

Tags: kernel-modules, hardware, temperature, sensors

I am trying to get the TMP102 kernel module functioning on an x86_64 machine running CentOS 7.6 (kernel 3.10). The system has 3 TMP102 sensors attached to an I2C bus (Designware I2C adapter).

When I load the TMP102 sensor module (source tree [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v3.10/drivers/hwmon/tmp102.c)), the module appears to detect all three of the sensors. At the tail of dmesg I see the "initiated" statements that display the I2C address for each sensor(from line 207 of source).

"Root" hwmon# sysfs files are creates for each sensor (e.g., `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon#`), but inside of each of these nodes the attribute files (`input`, `max`, and `max_hyst`) are missing; so no data can be queried from any of the sensors through `sysfs`.

I'm not sure exactly what is going wrong here. I've compared the driver code with similar sensors and they appear to follow the same overall pattern (registering attributes to the parent device node).

When I run `i2c-detect`, the sensors are visible. I can also query the sensors directly over the I2C bus and retrieve the current value without a problem; but I would prefer to use the TMP102 driver and sysfs for consistency.

Does anyone have any idea why the `sysfs` files are failing to be created, and/or the next steps I can take to fix and/or debug the issue?

Comment: Sounds like your issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37507609/user-space-application-for-tmp102-sensor-driver.

Comment: Docs on this H/W - http://www.ti.com/tool/tmp102sw-linux.

Comment: Looking at this - https://github.com/Mellanox/mlxsw/wiki/Temperature-and-Fan-Control I suspect your H/W is not getting fully detected by the tmp102 driver.